# use of assert and static assert functions

Tags: c++, assert, assertions, static-assert

I am trying to understand the use of static_assert and assert and what the difference is between  them, however there are very little sources/explantions about this

here is some **code**

```
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "cassert"
#include "iostream"


int main()
{
    assert(2+2==4);
    std::cout << "Execution continues past the first assert\n";
    assert(2+2==5);
    std::cout << "Execution continues past the second assert\n";
    _getch();
}
```

*comments on redundency will be appreciated(since I am learning "how to c++")*

**output in cmd**

```
Execution continues past the first assert
Assertion failed: 2+2==5, file c:\users\charles\documents\visual studio 2012\pro
jects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp, line 14
```

I have been trying to find out the different mehtods and uses of it, but as far as I understand it is a runtime check and another "type" of if statement

could someone just clarify the use and explain what each one does and they difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of assertions as sanity checks. You *know* that some condition *should* be true unless you've screwed something up, so the assertion *should* pass. If you have indeed screwed something up, the assertion will fail and you'll be told that something is wrong. It's just there to ensure the validity of your code.

A `static_assert` can be used when the condition is a constant expression. This basically means that the compiler is able to evaluate the assertion before the program ever actually runs. You will be alerted that a `static_assert` has failed at compile-time, whereas a normal `assert` will only fail at run time. In your example, you could have used a `static_assert`, because the expressions `2+2==4` and `2+2==5` are both constant expressions.

`static_assert`s are useful for checking compile-time constructs such as template parameters. For example, you could assert that a given template argument `T` must be a POD type with something like:

```
static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "T must be a POD type");
```

Note that you generally only want run-time assertions to be checked during debugging, so you can disable `assert` by `#define`ing `NDEBUG`.

Comment: thank you for your indepth explantation, i am just curios, are there any "#includes" that I need for an assert/static_assert to work?

Comment: for assert you need ``#include <cassert>`` (in C++), for static_assert there is no include. It is a compiler builtin if it is available. You need to compile for C++11/C11 though! (``-std=c++11``/``-std=c11`` argument for gcc).

Comment: @user2699451 For `static_assert`, you don't need to do anything. It's a language feature. For `assert`, you should include `<cassert>`.

Comment: @JonasWielicki That's right for C++11, but not for C11. C11 has `_Static_assert` as a new keyword, and a standard header (not sure which, probably `<assert.h>`) that defines `static_assert` as a macro expanding to `_Static_assert`. It's similar to `bool`/`_Bool` in C99, where `bool` is defined in `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: Oh interesting @hvd, didn’t know that!

Answer (score 2):

`assert()` is a macro whose expansion depends on whether macro `NDEBUG` is defined. If so, `assert()` doesn't expand to anything - it's a no-op. When `NDEBUG` is not defined, `assert(x)` expands into a runtime check, something like this:

```
if (!x) cause_runtime_to_abort()
```

It is common to define `NDEBUG` in "release" builds and leave it undefined in "debug" builds. That way, `assert()`s are only executed in debug code and do not make it into release code at all. You normally use `assert()` to check things which should always be true - a function's preconditions and postconditions or a class's invariants, for example. A failed `assert(x)` should mean "the programmer thought that `x` holds, but a bug somewhere in the code (or in their reasoning) made that untrue."

---

`static_assert()` (which was introduced in C++11) is a keyword - similar to e.g. `typedef`. It can only be used on *compile-time* expressions, and if it fails, it results in a compilation error. It does not result in any object code and is not executed at all.

`static_assert()` is primarily useful in templates, if you want to prevent instantiating a template incorrectly. For example:

```
template <class IntType>
IntType foo(IntType x)
{
  static_assert(std::is_integral<IntType>::value, "foo() may be used with integral types only.");
  // rest of the code
}
```

That way, trying to call `foo()` with e.g. a `float` will result in a compile-time error with a sensible message.

Occasionally, `static_assert()` can also be useful outside of templates, e.g. like this:

```
static_assert(sizeof(void*) > 4, "This code does not work in 32 bits");
```

Answer (score 1):

a `static_assert` is evaluated at compile time, an `assert` is evaluated an runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you cannot find any sources for this, but I’ll nevertheless give some explanation.

**`assert`** is for runtime checks which should never ever fail. If they fail, the program will terminate ungracefully. You can disable assertions for a release build by specifying a compile time flag. As assertions should never fail (they are assertions after all), in a working program, that should not make any difference. However, the expressions inside an assert **must not** have side effects, because there is no guarantee that they are executed. Example:

```
unsigned int add_non_negative_numbers(int a, int b)
{
    // good
    assert(a > 0);
    assert(b > 0);
    return (unsigned int)a + (unsigned int)b;
}

void checked_read(int fd, char *buffer, int count)
{
    // BAD: if assertions are disabled, read() will _not_ be called
    assert(read(fd, buffer, count) == count);
    /* better: not perfect though, because read can always fail
    int read_bytes = read(fd, buffer, count);
    assert(read_bytes == count);
    */
}
```

**`static_assert`** is new and can be used to perform compile time checks. They will produce a compiler error when they fail and block the program from compiling:

```
static_assert(sizeof(char) == 1, "Compiler violates the standard");
```